# Script fails to read file from beginning

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I am trying to parse an xml file with python script. The problem is that when i print the lines i can see that the script skips many lines and starts from (almost) the middle of the xml file. I actually made the **xml** into **txt** so it would be easier.

Here is my code:

```
file_fcm='path_to_file.txt'
with open(file_fcm,'r',encoding='utf-8') as hrd:
    hrd=hrd.readlines()
    for line in hrd:
        print(line)
```

**EDIT**

Here is a sample of the input file.
I added a comment to the line where the script starts reading:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<database DSN="test" Database="test  " SMT_DB="&lt;SMT DB&gt;" UTCExportTime="2020-06-23 08:09:49" DD_version="2.1.5" ExportType="Partition">
    <framerates>
        <framerate Name="80" Description="Eighty Hertz" PseudoRate="Y">
        </framerate>
        <framerate Name="20" Description="Twenty Hertz" PseudoRate="Y">
        </framerate>
        <framerate Name="10" Description="Ten Hertz" PseudoRate="Y">
        </framerate>
        <framerate Name="5" Description="Five Hertz" PseudoRate="Y">
        </framerate>
        <framerate Name="1" Description="One Hertz" PseudoRate="Y">
        </framerate>
    </framerates>
    <unittypes>
        <unittype Name="ft/lb" Description="Foot Pounds">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="deg" Description="degrees">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="ft/sec" Description="feet per second">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="ft" Description="feet">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="ft/sec^2" Description="feet per second square">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="lb/ft^2" Description="pound per foot square">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="deg/sec" Description="degree per second">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="radians" Description="radians">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="mv" Description="millivolt">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="nm" Description="nautical miles">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="kts" Description="knots">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="inHg" Description="inches mercury">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="ft/min" Description="feet per minute">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="deg C" Description="degrees Celsius">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="mach" Description="mach">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="g" Description="gravity constant">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="MHz" Description="mega hertz">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="mbar" Description="milli bar">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="V" Description="volt">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="Vrms" Description="volt root mean square">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="rpm" Description="revolutions per minute">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="in/lb" Description="torque">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="amps" Description="amperes">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="degM" Description="degrees of motor">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="psi" Description="pounds per square inch">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="rad/sec" Description="radians per seconds">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="deg/deg" Description="degree per degree">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="ft/sec/kt" Description="feet per second per knot">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="ft/sec/mach" Description="feet per second per mach">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="unitless" Description="unitless">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="sec" Description="seconds">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="deg/(ft/sec)" Description="degrees per (feet per second)">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="deg/(ft/sec^2)" Description="degrees per (feet per seconds square)">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="%MAC" Description="Percent of Mach">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="deg/ft" Description="degrees per feet">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="sec/ft" Description="seconds per feet">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="lb" Description="Pounds">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="fc" Description="foot-candles">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="deg/sec^2" Description="degrees per second square">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="in" Description="inches">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="deg/(g*sec)" Description="degrees per (g times seconds)">
        </unittype>
        <unittype Name="mA" Description="mili amperes">
        </unittype>
    </unittypes>
    <datatypes>
        <datatype Name="uint32" Description="Unsigned Integer" BitSize="32" MinValue="0" MaxValue="4294967295" IntegerOnly="Y">
        </datatype>
        <datatype Name="int32" Description="Signed Integer" BitSize="32" MinValue="-2147483648" MaxValue="2147483647" IntegerOnly="Y">
        </datatype>
        <datatype Name="boolean" Description="Boolean" BitSize="32" MinValue="0" MaxValue="1" IntegerOnly="Y">
        </datatype>
        <datatype Name="float" Description="Single Precision Floating Point" BitSize="32" MinValue="-1073741824" MaxValue="1073741824" IntegerOnly="N">
        </datatype>
    </datatypes>
    <partitions>
        <partition Name="fcm" Description="Flight Control Module; DAL=A" SMT_PartitionID="000000000">
            <dataobjects>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test- test point" Unit="deg" DataType="float" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="-50" MaxRange="50" IsTestPoint="Y" BitSize="">
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test- test point" Unit="deg" DataType="float" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="-50" MaxRange="50" IsTestPoint="Y" BitSize="">
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="int32" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="-2147483648" MaxRange="2147483647" IsTestPoint="Y" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="int32" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="-2147483648" MaxRange="2147483647" IsTestPoint="Y" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="N" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="N" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="N" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="N" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="N" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="N" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                </Signal>
                #THIS IS WHERE THE SCRIPT STARTS**<Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="N" BitSize="">** 
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="N" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="N" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="Y" BitSize="">
                </Signal>
                <Signal Name="test" Description="test" Unit="unitless" DataType="boolean" Scaling="" Sensing="Positive" InitialValue="0" MinRange="0" MaxRange="1" IsTestPoint="N" BitSize="">
                    <ProducedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ProducedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                    <ConsumedBy Function="test.test">
                    </ConsumedBy>
                </Signal>
```

**EDIT2**

I have 2 more similar xml files but **smaller** size and the script works fine on them. Could this be the problem?The size?

**EDIT3**

**So yes, i split the file into 4 smaller files and it works. Why does this happens though?**

Comment: Can you provide sample of your input file ? Also please write down the output you are getting.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What is the wanted output? Why not use an XML library, such as ElementTree?

Comment: @mzjn I just want to read the whole file at the beginning and then do some stuff. I thought txt would be easier. I never worked with xml files before.

Comment: What do you mean by "do some stuff"?

Comment: @mzjn For example some lines starts with <Signal... i want to get these lines. But i wanted firstly to read the whole document because it's skipping some signals

Comment: Please publish a `valid` xml file so we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A thing I would like to correct first.

You have named filepointer as `hrd` and then again using the same variable name for storing output of `readlines()`

Try this :

```
file_fcm='path_to_file.txt'
with open(file_fcm,'r',encoding='utf-8') as hrd:
    file_content = hrd.readlines()

for line in file_content:
print(line)
```

Comment: It's still the same :/

Comment: Can you please show the contents of input file and the output you are receiving ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `readlines` which will read a bunch of lines **or** enumerate the file object. If you mix them, you have a part of the file in the output of `readlines` and only process what remains after. The correct way to read the file is:

```
file_fcm='path_to_file.txt'
with open(file_fcm,'r',encoding='utf-8') as hrd:
    for line in hrd:
        print(line)
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same output :/

Comment: Is it really? Then give some input data so that we can reproduce...

Comment: Do you mean the file that is searching? I updated the answer with this. I added a comment to where the script starts printing as well